# How to hide partial view from MVC in specific websites

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, partial-views

I am using partial view in MVC for showing LogOn Form in GeneralLayout, but I want to hide this logOn form on specific websites. I did not find proper solution for this, tried many examples from here:

```
@if (window.location.href == 'Index/Map' || window.location.href == 'Index/Game') {
    $("#PartialView").hide();
}
```

or this:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
switch (pathname) {
    case "Index/Map":
        $("#PartialView").hide();
        break;
    case "Index/Game":
        $("#PartialView").hide();
        break;
```

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="main-content" id="HideButtons">

            <a id="logo" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Index")"></a>
            @if (PlayerSession.AppPlayerSession.IsLogged)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("LogOnForm");
            }
            else
            {
                <button class="button" id="logIn">Log In</button>
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: This should be handled from the backend and not from javascript. I would suggest to create an HtmlExtension to decide which action results should show or hide the loggin button and add an if logic with Razor

Comment: You are not checking **websites**, you are checking **pages on a single website**. Please be specific about what you mean and pay attention to the words that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code for hide and show login/logOut partial:

```
@if(User.Authenticated)
{ Html.RenderPartial("LogOnForm");}
```

and show partial:

```
 @if(!User.Authenticated)
{ Html.RenderPartial("LoginForm");}
```